# How to pass HashMap value to list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

How to pass hashmap value to List 
Entry is of type String key and value?

Page Class:

```
public List<Entry> entry;

public void setEntry(final List<Entry> entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
    this.setInfo(entry);
}

public void setInfo(final List<Entry> entryList) {   
    this.prop = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Entry objEntry : this.entry) {
        this.prop.put(objEntry.getKey(), objEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

I have created a map:

```
Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();
info.put("abc", "123")
```

I tried this:

```
List l = new ArrayList(info.values());
page.setInfo(list); // I am getting class cast exception
```

Comment: You're also getting warnings about not using generics properly, which leads to exactly that sort of exception.

Comment: This is why not to use raw types ... if you weren't using raw types this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: In Page class, setInfo method : enhanced for loop try replacing this.entry to entryList

Answer (score 1):

In your method of `public void setInfo(final List<Entry> entryList)` , you need a type of `List<Entry>`, while you pass a type which is `List<String>`.

If you are new to Generic, check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information.

So, for you case, you need an Entry type inside your List. Method  Map#`entrySet()` can do this, it returns a collection of Map.Entry.

You can create your list with the entry set like this:

```
   List<Entry> list = new ArrayList(info.entrySet());
```

Comment: If you need an Entry type inside your list, you need to get the collection of entry from your map.Method entrySet() can do this, it returns a collection of Map.Entry.

Comment: List<Entry> list = new ArrayList(info.entrySet());
page.setEntry(list);

Comment: I tried this.. but in setInfo. this.prop.put(objEntry.getKey(), objEntry.getValue());-- I am getting as null

Comment: @pals , so the problem out the exception is resolved. you are forlooping an this.entry, and you never use the pass param of List<Entry> entryList. Try replacing it into the passed list, or use `this.entry= entryList` before your loop.

Answer (score 0):

In Page class setInfo method, `enhanced for loop` try replacing **this.entry** to **entryList** as:

Page Class:

```
class Page {

public List<Entry> entry;

...

public void setInfo(final List<Entry> entryList) {   
    this.prop = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Entry objEntry : entryList) {
        this.prop.put(objEntry.getKey(), objEntry.getValue());
    }
  }
 }
```

Create your list with the entry set as: (as per @Jaskey)

```
 List<Entry> list = new ArrayList(info.entrySet());
```

Hope this helps